# Eliminate [annoyance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[annoyance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/annoyance) is a meta tag that serves only to diminish any question it is attached to.  Actually, it's not even a meta tag, it's a comment tag.  Recommend simply deleting it (4 questions, which makes this tag just an annoyance).

Comment: There are no tags tagged [annoyance] (someone must've got to them?)

Comment: That was fast!!